# jQuery .trigger not bubbling inside a jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, angularjs, coffeescript, mocha.js, jsfiddle

So in the following fiddle, I have one unit test failing, and its very odd. It would appear that jQuery's `.trigger` method firing but events are not bubbling even to its closest parent.

http://jsfiddle.net/fresheyeball/8875S/2/

```
it.only "clicking on and off", (done) ->
    $('#the-zone').parent().on 'click', -> 
        done()

    $('#the-zone').trigger 'click'
    expect(scope.didFire).to.be.null
```

I have done nothing to interfere with bubbling. What is going on here? It works fine with karma and phantomjs.

I know that event bubbling works in jsfiddle, what I can't figure out is why its not working in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an additional click handler on `#the-zone` that is preventing bubbling. removing it makes your test pass.

http://jsfiddle.net/8875S/4/

```
$('#the-zone').off("click").trigger 'click'
```

Figure out where that click event is coming from and clean it up there. I'm not familiar with coffeescript mocha or angularjs so i haven't been able to find the src click handler.

Comment: Adding `true` to after `isoff = <bool>` in your module solves it too, since otherwise it's returning the value of `isoff`. that threw me for a loop. i still despise coffeejs. you didn't tell it to return anything from that function, and yet it is. Guess you could also just add `return` instead for the same effect. http://jsfiddle.net/8875S/8/

Comment: Adding `return` is what I ended up doing. Just needed the nudge, thanks @Kevin.

Comment: No problem. One day i will make the dive into angularjs. just have to find the right time.